# Can AutoHotKey Create a Renaming Droplet?

Tags: autohotkey, renaming

I'm a clerical assistant.  When files get exported from our document management system, they arrive like this:

BIGNAME-#9999999-This_Is_The-File_Name_Right_Here.doc

I'd like to basically create an AutoHotKey droplet that chops off the BIGNAME and number, and then converts all the underscores to dashes, creating an end result of:

This Is The File Name Right Here.doc

Unfortunately, I'm still a bit of a newb when it comes to AutoHotKey, and I'm not even sure where to start.

Does anyone know if a script that heavily renames using AutoHotKey already exists, that I might model mine after?  Or any other tips towards accomplishing this project?

This small thing would be a huge help in my daily workflow -- so I appreciate any assistance you might offer in getting me to my destination.

(I'm open to non-AHK alternatives if anyone has suggestions.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you want to covert underscores to dashes, but your example  seems to convert both underscores and dashes to hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here's a script that solves the problem using AutoHotkey. The regular expressions work with the given example - they will of course need tweaking if the pattern differs.

Dropping a file onto this script's file will calculate the new filename and prompt the user to rename it.

```
; Save dropped file path to a variable.
DroppedFilePath = %1%

; Convert the dropped file path to a long filename.
Loop, %DroppedFilePath%, 1
    DroppedFilePathLong := A_LoopFileLongPath

; Create seperate variables for the filename and folder.
SplitPath, DroppedFilePathLong, OutFileName, OutDir

; Use a RegEx to find the start and length of the '#9999999-' string.
Start := RegExMatch(OutFileName, "P)#[0-9]+-", Length)

; Exit now if the RegEx didn't match anything.
If Length < 1
    {
    MsgBox File does not match pattern.
    ExitApp
    }

; Add the start and length positions to get the position at the end of the '#9999999-' string.
EndString := SubStr(OutFileName, Start + Length)

; Replace hypens and underscores with spaces.
Result := RegExReplace(EndString, "(-|_)", " ")

; Add our new filename to the existing folder name to a variable.
ResultPath := OutDir . "\" . Result

; Prompt the user - make sure we got things right.
MsgBox, 36, Rename File, Rename file`n`n%OutFileName%`n`nto`n`n%Result%?
IfMsgBox, No
    ExitApp

; Rename the file.
FileMove, %DroppedFilePath%, %ResultPath%

ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a Windows Explorer alternative called [FreeCommander](http://www.freecommander.com/).

As well as having a really convenient view of two folders side-by-side, it has a flexible renaming facility.

**Edit**

So here's how it works (it's a lot simpler than this detailed list makes it sound - really!)

- After selecting your file or files, hit File -> Multi Rename. The short-cut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.
- You get the following dialog
- At the bottom of the screen is the text you want to remove, and what you want to replace it with.
- This creates a kind of rule or pattern
- Notice that you can save each of these rules as a Profile, for re-use
- At the top of the dialog, it shows for each selected file, the original name and the new one
- You should also turn off "Close dialog after Rename" - I forgot this when taking the screenshots
- (Obviously) Click on Rename

[image]

- That's your first renaming done
- In the second screenshot, I've replaced underscores with spaces
- Notice I also checked "Replace all occurrences", and saved this as a profile too

[image]

Now the file is renamed, as you wanted. (If you really wanted to get rid of the hyphen, you could do that too)

That's the recipe set up. In future, you can select any number of files, and do Batch rename, then apply each of these two profiles to renaming all your files in just a few steps.

(And if this were still too many steps, you could always record an AutoHotKey macro to replace these steps...)

If all you want to do is renaming lots of files, there are lots of specific tools available, and this may be too complex.

For example, in the past I made heavy use of [**Flash Renamer**](http://www.rlvision.com/flashren/about.asp)

But the thing I like about FreeCommander is that it has so many other really useful features (such as quick-filtering, to show only files with particular text in their names), that it saves me a huge amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the free "[Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php)", or the command-line version, called [Bulk Rename Command](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Command.php).